# How does AJAX Chat Servers like PHPFreeChat work?

Tags: php, ajax, chat, irc

This is probably a newb question. How does a chat server like PHPFreeChat Works? I've always had the impression that a server must be a windows service which manages TCP Connections. However for PHPFreeChat, there is no service.

Can someone give a general idea? Can't seem to find this information even in the Chat websites

Thanks!

Comment: that has to be ajax... Their description is like this: "It uses AJAX to smoothly refresh (no flicker) and display the chat zone and the nickname zone."

Comment: It use Ajax (http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) to send your request (your message) to server, and for each other who viewing the chat, the web page refresh (actually just a the chat part has refresh and that how Ajax help you)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned above, the messages are usually stored in some means of permanent storage like a text file or database. In simple ones anyway, the page polls the storage at a specific interval (500ms) and appends the new messages to the chat window.

The server is polled using AJAX which can send form variables using Javascript so it can receive the server response without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

It actually works by storing each PHP Chat messages in either a text file or a Database.
It does not use IRC or a windows service which manages TCP Connections